# How to make a Blur gradient SVG-CSS

Tags: javascript, css, svg, gradient, mask

I tried to create two divs, applying a gradient to the upper one, and adding a backdrop filter to the lower one. It resulted in a continuous blur effect, which doesn't suit my needs.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwOww.png

how to make the blur effect more subtle so the edges won't be that strong like
[on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uc8Ff.png)

Comment: You can use something like `.blur:nth-child(#{$i})` in SCSS.

Comment: the main idea to try to make the blur effect more subtle so the edges won't be that strong like on image

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.